# Python/Flask deployment without pip

Tags: python, deployment, flask, web-deployment

I've usually deployed my Flask applications with a fairly simple fabric script that put the source on the target machine, used pip to install any dependencies, then fired up uwsgi with all the necessary settings and off it went.

However, I have a new issue that some new security settings in our environments have blocked us from access outside the network so trying to use pip to install our dependencies fails. I looked into using `python setup.py sdist` to create a package thinking this would build everything down on the developer machine then I could upload the .tar.gz to the deployment machine and install it but it is still trying to contact pip to get the dependencies.

Is there a way to get a completely compiled package with dependencies and all that I could use to deploy to my server? Is there some `sdist` setting I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your build machine is binary-compatible with the target, or you don't need any compiled extensions, you can use `pip wheel` to compile you project and all its dependencies to wheels, copy those files to the server, and `pip install` from the wheel directory only.

```
# on build machine
cd myproject
pip wheel --wheel-dir wheelbase .
scp -r wheelbase me@target.example.org

# on target machine
pip install --no-index --find-links=wheelbase myproject
```

You should be able to copy the odd sdist into the --find-links directory as well, in which case pip will install from the sdist, if you have to recompile on the server.

Comment: This looks promising. I tried your way and it seems like it didn't install all the packages I needed. I tried building the wheel from the requirements.txt file which seemed to get all my packages now but when I tried to install them on the box I got  MarkupSafe-0.23-cp27-none-linux_i686.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. I looked in the wheel directory and it has that wheel. My dev machine is Ubuntu and my target is CentOS. Any suggestions?

Comment: Download the MarkupSafe sdist and put it in the wheel directory too. Pip should be smart enough to build that the target machine. Or just build on a CentOS VM. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MarkupSafe

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing the latter. Built on an existing centos machine and copied the wheeldir over. Seems to have everything I need now.